# To find who's binded to an event and use if and else if with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called in multiple ways.

```
function func1(){
    if(){               //called by an onclick event
       alert("!");
    }else if(){         //called by another function - 
       alert("?");      //ex) - $(document).ready(function(){ func1()}
 }
```

is there any way to determine if the function is bound by which event and use it with my if and else if lines? Please help.

Comment: You can look at the arguments passed to the function... A click handlers's arguments are pretty specific.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Just add a parameter: `function func1(e) { ...`. If the function is handling an event, the event gets passed as first parameter. `if (e) ...` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several options. I use both depending on the situation.

1) Seperate the event handlers from the other function and use a parameter.

```
<button id="button_validate_form">Validate</button>
<button id="button_submit_form">Sumbit</button>
const doWork = function doWork( event, context ) {
    if ( context === 'event_validate_form' ) alert( '!' );
    else if ( context === 'event_submit_form' ) alert( '?' );
    else alert( 'undefined event' );
};
document.querySelector( '#button_validate_form' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => doWork( event, 'event_validate_form' ) );
document.querySelector( '#button_submit_form' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => doWork( event, 'event_submit_form' ) );
```

2) Same story, but instead of adding a parameter to the function, use a data attribute on the actual DOM node.

```
<button id="button_validate_form" data-context="event_validate_form">Validate</button>
<button id="button_submit_form" data-context="event_validate_form">Sumbit</button>
const doWork = function doWork( event ) {
    const context = event.target.getAttribute( 'data-context' );
    if ( context === 'event_validate_form' ) alert( '!' );
    else if ( context === 'event_submit_form' ) alert( '?' );
    else alert( 'undefined event' );
};
document.querySelector( '#button_validate_form' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => doWork( event, 'event_validate_form' ) );
document.querySelector( '#button_submit_form' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => doWork( event, 'event_submit_form' ) );
```